# How to stop Android Studio from going full-screen on Windows?

Tags: android, android-studio

Ever since the version before Giraffe, Android Studio jumps to full-screen mode on Windows whenever I exit with the [X] button on the upper-right. So the next time I open Android Studio it's full-screen and I have to adjust it back to what I want. With the latest version of Giraffe it's now even doing this when using Alt-F4 to exit.

Is Google aware of this and will they fix it? Or is there some fix/workaround now that will address this bad behavior?

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac I went to:

```
Android Studio -> Settings
```

I enabled the "new UI" you can see here:
[image: screenshot of settings]

and then I had an option to Minimize/Maximize the screen.

Hope it helps. I had the same problem.

Comment: At first I thought this would work but it doesn't. Same issue of the app going full-screen upon exit when pressing the [X] in the upper right of the window on Windows.